# Regex for string data with consecutive five digits with any alphabets

Tags: regex

I want a regex expression which allows five consecutive numbers, the string may contain any other alphabet, but no other numbers.

```
A12345 - true
12345B - true
AH16478 - true
12678As - true
A - false
A1234 - false
12329 - true
A12S672J - false
A18999Gh26738 - false
```

I have tried with \d{5} but it allows another set of consecutive numbers. I want only one set of consecutive five numbers and rest not bothered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use:

```regex
^[A-Z]*[0-9]{5}[A-Z]*$
```

This pattern requires a single sequence of 5 digits, with optional capital letters on either side of that sequence.